# Hide non working hours in datetime fields in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there any way to filter the date time control to show only the working hours when creating a new task, phone call, email, appointment, etc.

I have configured the working hours for a user [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy2Dn.png), and the calendar now shows the correct working hours. But when the user creates a new task, the control that displays the due date shows all the hours, beginning from 12:00 AM. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srleg.png)

Any suggestions on how to filter that field according to the working hours previously defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out how to hide some hours of the date and time field. In my case, the start hour and the end hour is hardcoded (from 07:00 AM to 06:30 PM).

This is the javascript that makes the magic.

```
function InitializeDateTimeControls(){
    var scheduledendAttr = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('scheduledend');
    var scheduledstartAttr = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('scheduledstart');
    if(scheduledendAttr != null)
    {
        RemoveNotWorkingHours('scheduledend');
        SetActualDueDate('scheduledend');
    }
    if(scheduledstartAttr != null)
    {
        RemoveNotWorkingHours('scheduledstart');
        SetActualDueDate('scheduledstart');
    }
};

function RemoveNotWorkingHours(controlname) {
    if(Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() == 1)
    {

        var timetable = $("td[id^='" + controlname + "Time.']");

        timetable.each(function () {

        var time = $(this)[0].innerText;

        var hours = time.substring(0, time.indexOf(":"));

        var mins = time.substring(time.indexOf(":") + 1, time.indexOf(":") + 3);

        var am_pm = time.substring(time.indexOf(" ") + 1, time.indexOf(" ") + 3);


        var fulltime = hours + ":" + mins + " " + am_pm;


            var hourint = +hours;
            if((hourint < 7 || hourint == 12) && am_pm == 'AM')
            {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            }
            if((hourint > 6 && hourint != 12) && am_pm == 'PM')
            {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            }


        });
    }

};

function SetActualDueDate(controlname)
{
    if(Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() == 1)
    {
        var dueDate = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get(controlname);
        var now = new Date();
        dueDate.setValue(now);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported way to do that.

Unsupported (never really a good idea) you could probably write some JavaScript and manipulate the DOM to change the pick list values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was concerned about this. And now I know that there's not a supported way to accomplish it.